# Fetching a part of field name by searching for a character pattern

Tags: sql, pattern-matching, character, substr

I have a field that has values like:

```
ABCD3 100MG

EFGHI 0.5 UNITS/ML

JKL MNO PQR

STU V 100-1.5 MCG ABC

W-X/Y Z 100-750
...
```

These values are just a sample (there could be more patterns)

I am looking to write a query to fetch only the first character portion of the values, in this example:

```
ABCD3

EFGHI

JKL MNO PQR

STU V

W-X/Y Z
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thought - Use a substring type function to capture all text before '%%'? I could get to this because there is no set number of characters or position to look for, and could not generalize numbers (there may be a different way to do this).

***Using SQL Server 2008 R2

Examples are appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/iV8cC3/3 ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj actually that's the answer. I was testing without success something like `^\D+`

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes I know, that's why I mentioned you that yours was the answer :P

Comment: not sure whether the regex will work on sql :-)